# Can different person see different shared folder structure by file sharing services of Windows Server 2008 r2?

Tags: network-shares, windows-server-2008-r2, file-sharing, windows-domain, file-server

For example, I have a folder structure like bellow in Windows Server 2008 R2 server:

```
ShareFolder  
  SubFolder1  
    File1  
  SubFolder2  
    SSFolder1  
      File2  
    SSFolder2  
      File3
```

And I want to share the folder like this:
`UserA` have only Read/Write permissions on `SubFolder1`;
`UserB` have only Read permissions on `SSFolder2`.

So when `UserA` open the Server from FileExplorer/Network in his/her own computer, he/she will see a folder struture like bellow:

```
ShareFolder  
  SubFolder1  
    File1
```

And `UserB` like bellow:

```
ShareFolder  
  SubFolder2  
    SSFolder2  
      File3
```

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!
The first trick is I should create the root share with the File Server Resource Manager and tune the permissions of the sub-folder from the Windows Explorer. This is to make sure that the shared folders arranged with parent-child structure, not shoulder by shoudlder.
The second is enable the "[Access-based Enumeration](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772681(v=ws.10).aspx)" of the root shared folder.